# How edit or alter the links in the secondary toolbar?

Tags: navigation, 9

I'm on D9.3.x with Gin theme and Gin Toolbar.

I need to edit the link available in the *secondary toolbar*.

Namely, I'd need to hide the *shortcuts* link for everyone and hide the *edit profile* sub-link for some roles.

Is that possible to do somehow via configuration? I could find nothing, so I've also tried to use `hook_toolbar_alter`. However, I can't understand how the "user" link part is build, so I can't actually hide the *edit* link - I'll attach below the export of `$items['user']` variable.

Any suggestions on how solve this? Thanks

```php
 [
    '#type' => 'toolbar_item',
    'tab' =>
      [
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#title' =>
          [
            '#lazy_builder' =>
              [
                0 => 'user.toolbar_link_builder:renderDisplayName',
                1 =>
                  [
                  ],
              ],
            '#create_placeholder' => TRUE,
          ],
        '#url' =>
          Drupal\Core\Url::__set_state([
            'urlGenerator' => NULL,
            'urlAssembler' => NULL,
            'accessManager' => NULL,
            'routeName' => 'user.page',
            'routeParameters' =>
              [
              ],
            'options' =>
              [
              ],
            'external' => FALSE,
            'unrouted' => FALSE,
            'uri' => NULL,
            'internalPath' => NULL,
            '_serviceIds' =>
              [
              ],
            '_entityStorages' =>
              [
              ],
          ]),
        '#attributes' =>
          [
            'title' =>
              Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup::__set_state([
                'string' => 'My account',
                'arguments' =>
                  [
                  ],
                'translatedMarkup' => NULL,
                'options' =>
                  [
                  ],
                'stringTranslation' => NULL,
              ]),
            'class' =>
              [
                0 => 'toolbar-icon',
                1 => 'toolbar-icon-user',
              ],
          ],
        '#cache' =>
          [
            'contexts' =>
              [
                0 => 'user.roles:anonymous',
              ],
          ],
      ],
    'tray' =>
      [
        '#heading' =>
          Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup::__set_state([
            'string' => 'User account actions',
            'arguments' =>
              [
              ],
            'translatedMarkup' => NULL,
            'options' =>
              [
              ],
            'stringTranslation' => NULL,
          ]),
        'user_links' =>
          [
            '#lazy_builder' =>
              [
                0 => 'user.toolbar_link_builder:renderToolbarLinks',
                1 =>
                  [
                  ],
              ],
            '#create_placeholder' => TRUE,
          ],
      ],
    '#weight' => 1000,
    '#attached' =>
      [
        'library' =>
          [
            0 => 'user/drupal.user.icons',
          ],
      ],
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_toolbar_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_toolbar_alter(&$items) {
  // Remove the 'Shortcuts' toolbar item.
  unset($items['shortcuts']);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_links__toolbar_user(&$variables) {
  // Remove the 'Edit profile' menu item.
  unset($variables['links']['account_edit']);
}
```

One could also [override the *user.toolbar_link_builder* service](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services) for even more control.